# date format in /etc/hosts.allow

Tags: hosts

I have following line in my /etc/hosts.allow

```
sshd: 1.2.3.4 : spawn (echo `date` ALLOWED from %a >> /var/log/%d.log) &
```

The problem is, the date command prints time in the standard format, such as

```
Thu May 16 15:54:55 CEST 2013
```

which is complicated to process with my script. I would like to have `date` to specify my own format, such as `date "+%F %T"`, to get following format:

```
2013-05-16 16:01:07
```

even if I escape the special characters (%), the following does not work:

```
sshd: 1.2.3.4 : spawn (echo `date "+\%F \%T` ALLOWED from %a >> /var/log/%d.log)
```

Could somebody please advise ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double the percent sign, and it should work:

```
sshd: 1.2.3.4 : spawn (echo `date "+%%F %%T"` ALLOWED from %a >> /var/log/%d.log) &
```

For more information, see the "% Expansion" section of the corresponding [man page (`hosts_access(5)`)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts_access).